how to fix AttributeError: 'mesh' object has no attribute 'create_normals_split'
I'm new to all of this, so I have no idea how to fix this, and I can't seem to find any answer to my problem.
I'm trying to make some skin mods for a certain anime styled fantasy game using 3dmigoto, and when trying to import one of the character models, I get the error listed above and nothing loads. I was following a tutorial on Youtube, and the guy didn't have any kind issues, so I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong? I even tried importing a weapon model instead, but I get the same error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Hello and welcome to BSE. Can you share the model

The function create_normals_split was removed in Blender 4.1. Fixing this requires the importer authors to update their addon. In the meantime, you can use Blender 4.0 (or whatever the version in the youtube video you're following uses, since you know that one will work).

thank you @scurest! getting the previous version of Blender fixed my problem!
